# RubyInline - Compare String

Tags: ruby, string, inline

I have the following Inline C function which helps in comparing two arrays. I have to compare every element in Array 1 with Array 2 and get the count.

```
    builder.c '
      VALUE arr_distance(VALUE arr1, VALUE arr2){            
        long arr1_len = RARRAY_LEN(arr1);
        long arr2_len = RARRAY_LEN(arr2);            
        if(arr1_len == 0 || arr2_len == 0){
          return 0.0;
        }
        else{
          long i, j;
          VALUE count = 0;
          VALUE *c_arr1 = RARRAY_PTR(arr1);
          VALUE *c_arr2 = RARRAY_PTR(arr2);

          for(i = 0; i < arr1_len; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < arr2_len; j++){
              if(c_arr1[i] == c_arr2[j]){ //This comparison does not work
                count++;
              }
            }
          }
          return count;
        }            
      }'
```

How can i compare two strings to check if they are same with Inline C Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Convert Ruby string to C string using `RSTRING_PTR`, then use `strcmp` to compare string equality.</del>

Use `rb_str_cmp`:

```
require 'inline'

class Hello
  inline(:C) do |builder|
    builder.c '
      VALUE arr_distance(VALUE arr1, VALUE arr2){            
        long arr1_len = RARRAY_LEN(arr1);
        long arr2_len = RARRAY_LEN(arr2);            
        if(arr1_len == 0 || arr2_len == 0){
          return INT2NUM(0);
        }
        else{
          long i, j;
          int count = 0;
          VALUE *c_arr1 = RARRAY_PTR(arr1);
          VALUE *c_arr2 = RARRAY_PTR(arr2);

          for(i = 0; i < arr1_len; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < arr2_len; j++){
              if(rb_str_cmp(c_arr1[i], c_arr2[j]) == 0){
                count++;
              }
            }
          }
          return INT2NUM(count);
        }            
      }'
  end
end

p Hello.new.arr_distance(['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '4', '8', '1']) # => 2
```

Don't forget to convert C int to Ruby `Fixnum` using `INT2NUM`.

**UPDATE**

You can also use `rb_str_equal`:

```
if (rb_str_equal(c_arr1[i], c_arr2[j])) ...
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Very much! Is there a similar way to check if `c_arr[i] is a substring of c_arr[j]` ?

Comment: @JSWorld, Use `strstr(RSTRING_PTR(c_arr[j]), RSTRING_PTR(c_arr[i])) != NULL`.

Comment: @JSWorld, For other string related functions, find `rb_str_*` in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/intern.h

Comment: I need to make a small change to return `arr1_len/count` instead of just `count`. But that always returns an INT. Do we need to do anything additionally to make it return `double`? Thanks..

Comment: @JSWorld, Please post a separated question instead of comment.

Comment: I have asked a separate question with my full logic here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830251/ruby-inline-returning-double-values. Thanks...